# Avoiding tiling/mosaicing in resulting image when Pan-sharpening Gram-Schmidt?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, smoothing, pansharpening

I mastered to georeference some declassified Hexagon satellite imagery from the 60s and would like to use it to pan sharpen a current Sentinel satellite image (already done as RGB). It is very important for me to retain as much color information from the original (the Sentinel) image as possible.

The Gram-Schmidt seems to be the best method for this purpose as it is the only one retaining enough color information from the RGB image.

When using ArcMap's "Image Analysis" tool to pan sharpen, the image looks perfect. But once exported to GeoTiff steps/tiling/mosaicing become aparent in the exportet image (see attachment).

I understand that this cannot be entirely avoided due to the method used that retains as much color information as possible but is there any way to make those steps more smooth/less obvious?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Do your original hexagon images show any kind of tiling or does it appera only after the pansharpening ?

Comment: There is n tiling in the original image. It seems to be related to how Arcgis handles some kind of conditional Gram-Schmidt pan sharpening for different parts of the image. When moving around in ArcMap when zoomed in to the image the colors change slightly. This of course doesn't work in the exported GeoTiff. What I need is those differently colored parts to have smooth gradients. Not sure if I'm missing something in the export options of ArcGis.When the checking the renderer for exporting the image, the tiles are not there anymore but most of the color information gets lost also.

Comment: I just added two more images to me initial post.
One that shows the pan sharpened image with the black slide corners cropped. So the tiling I mean becomes more clear.
Another one that shows the original Hexagon image. No tiling there before the pan sharpening (they wouldn't have had the technique for pixelated tiling on a slide back in the 60ies anyway...)

Comment: So there seems to be no resolution for this problem? Who else could pansharpening work by retaining most of the original color information?

Comment: Compute full statistics on the input rasters before pansharpen and export.